# How to delete a WORD in insert mode?

Tags: key-bindings

I know that I can press Ctrl-W to delete a word in insert mode, but how would I delete a WORD?

For example, with this text

```
foo.bar.baz
          ^ (cursor position)
```

the command should delete all the way to foo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's none. Hint: if you think you may be missing something, try browsing through `:h quickref`.

Insert mode is not supposed to replace Normal mode. So it lacks many commands and stuff. Just switch to Normal and do `dB` or something like that.

But if you really believe you want it then use mappings, e.g.

```
inoremap <c-b> <c-\><c-o>dB
```